# Importing Excel Data into SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008r2-express

There seems to have been many discussions on this but I couldn't find something specific to what I am looking for. I am trying to use a query to import data from Excel to an existing table in SQL Server.

My query is:

```
INSERT INTO DailyRawData
   SELECT *
   FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                   'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=NO;
                   Database=C:\Users\home\Desktop\SQLImportTrim.xls', [data$]);
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" does not contain the table "data$". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

I don't  think this is a permission issue for me as I am set up as SysAdmn. I am wondering if the error is due to the last part of the query `[data$]` since this is what the error msg refers to. FYI the name of the excel file is `SQLImportTrim` and the tab that contains all my data is named `data`. There is no table named `data` in my Excel file. Is my query correct?

Comment: What is the tab name in your spreadsheet?

Comment: the tab name is "data"

Comment: Try changing your tab name to something else and see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

you don't use [data$] you use the name of the sheet, so the standard starting point is usually [Sheet1$] if you haven't renamed it.